# Navbar rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, router

[Navbar.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Sfs.png)

I have an issue when I was creating a react project. The problem is with the Navbar rendering.
The terminal shows no problem detected. but the browser shows the error. Here is below my attached copy of error[Navbar rendering issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcN3T.png)

My code is here [Navbar.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYinx.png)

[MY code second half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBr6W.png)

[Here is below attached app.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7ppm.jpg)

Comment: Please paste your code in text in your question, as well as the error you get.

Comment: Can you share more of your code, please?
The pictures are not enough

Comment: If you're going to include images in your question, don't include links, but rather have the images render inline. For more help, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310921/how-do-i-display-inline-image-in-a-post-on-stack-exchange-stack-overflow-not.